# Redux action must be plain objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have the following actions code:

```
let nextTodoId = 0

export const addTodo = text => ({
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  id: nextTodoId++,
  text
})
 
export const setVisibilityFilter = filter => ({
  type: 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER',
  filter
})
 
export const toggleTodo = id => ({
  type: 'TOGGLE_TODO',
  id
})

export const getResult = () => { type: 'GET_RESULT' }
 
export const VisibilityFilters = {
  SHOW_ALL: 'SHOW_ALL',
  SHOW_COMPLETED: 'SHOW_COMPLETED',
  SHOW_ACTIVE: 'SHOW_ACTIVE'
}
```

when "getResult" gets dispatched I get this error: "actions must be plain objects".

Am I not returning an object like this?

```
export const getResult = () => { type: 'GET_RESULT' }
```

If I change the above to:

```
export const getResult = { type: 'GET_RESULT' }
```

then it's all good

[image]

even after modifying the code with the possible solutions, I am still getting the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your object in braces otherwise the function will return undefined.

```
export const getResult = () => ({ type: 'GET_RESULT' });
```

You also need to call your `getResult` function inside the `dispatch`.

```
getResult: () => dispatch(getResult())
```

Comment: I am still getting the error. Take a look at the screenshot

Answer (score 2):

Your code

```
export const getResult = () => { type: 'GET_RESULT' }
```

transpiles into

```
var getResult = function() { 
    { type: 'GET_RESULT' }
};
```

which returns undefined, hence the error. If you change it into expression it will work:

```
export const getResult = () => ({ type: 'GET_RESULT' })
```

That's because it transpiles into:

```
var getResult = function() { 
    return { type: 'GET_RESULT' };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No you're not without parens you are creating an arrow function body, just use the syntax you've used above:

```
export const getResult = () => ({ type: 'GET_RESULT' });
```